# Vim shows file name as title

Tags: vim

My vim window shows filename on the top of the terminal window. I can't seem to find configuration related to that in my vimrc file to disable it. Any help on which variable need to be reset for removing this?

Comment: The top of the window is called the title bar.  Giving you the benefit of a doubt, if you google "vim title", this is the third search result [Changing Vim's Title](http://usevim.com/2012/06/13/set-title/)

Answer (score 6):

yes, you can set `title` option.

add this into your vimrc to disable the default title:

```
set notitle
```

for detailed info: `:h 'title'`

Comment: @adarsh003 check the output of `set title?` , some plugin may change the option for you. try starting vim without plugins

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and had to grovel through the source code to find the answer.

For some reason you need to set both `notitle` and `noicon`. It turns out the help text mentions this, but it's not intuitive.

Add these two lines to your .vimrc:

```
set notitle
set noicon
```